# Google authentication Free Radius Server stop working

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, freeradius

It is very funny issue. THe Free radius server has been up and running  for almost one year, no any issue. All the sudden it stops working this week.

I test the domain user from local:

```
radtest jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy 'yyy11111' localhost 18120 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812     
User-Name = "jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy"
User-Password = "yyy11111"
NAS-IP-Address = 10.10.10.10
NAS-Port = 18120

Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = "jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy"
User-Password = "yyy11111"
NAS-IP-Address = 10.10.10.10
NAS-Port = 18120

Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = "jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy"
User-Password = "yyy11111"
NAS-IP-Address = 10.10.10.10
NAS-Port = 18120
Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000   " 

radclient: no response from server for ID 149 socket 3
```

But the Radius.log shows  Auth: Login OK. 
debug shows..

```
+- entering group authenticate {...}
pam_pass: using pamauth string <radiusd> for pam.conf lookup
pam_pass: authentication succeeded for <jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy>
++[pam] returns ok
Login OK: [jzwang@yyy.yyy.yy/yyy11111] (from client localhost port 18120)
```

I switch to Pam_unix.so and test local user account, works well. Only Domain user accounts (using Pam_lsass.so) have issues.

Comment: SO is a developers site, this question is not about development, but  more likely for serverfault or another stack exchange administrators site (ubuntu?), see here : https://serverfault.com/ .

Comment: Thank you for let me know, I must click the wrong link...